# How can I add a specific loop in an array index

Tags: php, arrays

Hi guys this is my code:

```
$Months = array(
    'Jan',
    'Feb',
    'Mar',
    'Apr',
    'May',
    'Jun',
    'Jul',
    'Aug',
    'Sep',
    'Oct',
    'Nov',
    'Dec'
);


foreach($Months as $value){  
    echo "$value ";
    echo date('Y');
    echo "<br>";

    foreach(range(1,31) as $Days) {
        echo $Days;
         echo " ";
    }

    echo "<br>";
}
```

and this is the output:

```
Jan 2017

1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 

Feb 2017

1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31
```

and so on.

How can I edit the index to output the following months and it's days.

Comment: I am not quite sure what the desired output is. Can you also hardcode an example in your question?

Answer (score 4):

```
foreach($Months as $key=>$value){  
    echo "$value ";
    echo date('Y');
    echo "<br>";
    $year = 2017;
    echo implode(" ", range(1, cal_days_in_month(CAL_GREGORIAN, $key+1, $year)));

    echo "<br>";
}
```

Comment: Suggestion: you have the range of dates `range(1, cal_days_in_month(CAL_GREGORIAN, $key+1, $year))` in an array. Why loop to echo it? You can just`echo implode(" ", range(1, cal_days_in_month(CAL_GREGORIAN, $key+1, $year)));`